# problem with strings in script powershell sudo

Tags: powershell, sudo, strings

im making a script like sudo, the idea is that the sudo function is going to run a scriptblock in elevation. I'm having trouble with the strings variables, that i pass in that scriptblock. Is like the doubles quotes disappear.
What is wrong with my approach?
Here is the code.

```
function sud([ScriptBlock]$SomeCode){
$here = Get-Location;
Start-Process Powershell -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-command &{cd $here; $SomeCode}" 
}
```

and i want to run commands like this:

```
$var ="Path"
$newpath = $env:path + ";c:\somedir"
$target = "Machine"
sud -somecode { [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($var, $newpath, $target)}
```

for testing purpose one can add the parameter -noexit to the argumentlist..

```
Start-Process Powershell -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-noexit","-command &{cd $here; $SomeCode}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the command in single ticks and moving the double quote to the front of the actual command. This is what I do in my environment.

```
Start-Process Powershell -Verb Runas -ArgumentList `-command "&{cd $here; $SomeCode}"`
```